# small jquery parser

Tags: javascript

input is a string (var str) something like this:

```
"<<hello there//abcd//1234>>"
```

I want to know how to best extract the information to have this:

```
var a = "hello there";
var b = "abcd";
var c = 1234;
```

case a:  select everything after << until first // 
case b:  select everything after first // until second //
case c:  select everything after second // until >>

Anybody knows a simple solution?
THX

Comment: How is this related to jQuery?

Comment: @Johua: I removed the jQuery tag, since this is a job for Javascript.

Comment: The JavaScript regex engine hasn't been *ported* to jQuery. Not yet :P

Comment: Hy guys, jQuery/javascript doesn't really matter, the underlying of jQuery is actually javascript, and cause i'm working more with jquery i forgott to write javascript. But you'r right, me neither can see an jquery improvement in such situations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var value = "<<hello there//abcd//1234>>";
value = value.substring(2, value.length-2);

var array = value.split("//");
var a = array[0];
var b = array[1];
var c = array[2];
```

Or instead of substring, you can use `value = value.slice(2, -2);` (thanks to 
[Andy E's head](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94197/andy-es-head) for the alternative).

Comment: +1 but please correct this... the last is now `1234>>`... should have been `1234` only..

Comment: If you use `slice` instead of substring, you can use a negative value in the arguments: `value.slice(2, -2);`

Comment: @GenericTypeTea - here is a demo of what I mean... http://jsfiddle.net/5W7P3/ and also `substring` should be `substr`...

Comment: @Riegel: no, it shouldn't.  `substr` is not defined in the ECMAScript specification, and it doesn't work the same across all browsers.  Change your fiddle to `substring` and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/5W7P3/1/

Comment: No. substring is correct. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp. Here's my code, working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/CyeW3/

Comment: ahhh okay... I got now the confusion part.. sorry @GenericTypeTea... thanks @Andy E's head...

Answer (score 4):

If you can be sure the inner strings will not contain `/`, `>` or `<`, you can do this with a one-liner:

```
"<<hello there//abcd//1234>>".match(/[^<>/]+/g)
// -> ["hello there", "abcd", "1234"]
```

Comment: @GenericTypeTea: Actually, I was writing an answer similar to yours, and then the alert bar popped up with your answer in it, I decided to quickly change my solution so it wasn't a duplicate answer lol ;-)

Comment: Thanks i will try it later and come back here. Regex is very cool, but i still don't have the will to learn something what's not so friendly to understand. Be back

Answer (score 1):

split it into an array using the '//' as the delimiter. You then have an array of three elements. Then for the first element use substring to get rid of the first two characters and for the last element us substring again to get rid of the last two characters.

This uses javascript rather than jquery specifically

Answer (score 1):

```
var myOldString ="<<hello there//abcd//1234>>"
var myNewString = myOldString.replace("<<", '');
myNewString = myOldString.replace(">>", '');

var arrayofstring = myNewString .split("///")

var a = arrayofstring[0];
var b = arrayofstring[1];
var c = arrayofstring[2];
```

Comment: there's a mistake in the above I think:
var myOldString ="<>" 
var myNewString = myOldString.replace("<<", ''); 
myNewString = myNewString.replace(">>", '');

Comment: you could combine both the replaces and maybe even split - `"<<hello there//abcd//1234>>".replace(/^<<|>>$/g, '').split('//')`